# problems with deploying react project on netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify

[netlify giving me error cant figure it out. I tried CI= npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joM8T.png)

Comment: Maybe set the title more related to your error. You have a dependency error when installing modules

Answer (score 1):

Have you deployed a previous version of this project to netlify. If so, it's possible that you may want to deploy this as a new project after deleting the original. If not, [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/29/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-on-netlify/) has deployment docs, you could look through. Hope this helps!

Comment: this is the original

Answer (score 0):

This errors happened whith node version 16 and later, apparently. The reason is related to package-lock.json module versions. If you do not have a `package-lock.json` in your repo, the dependency changes every time you build. Some modules might cause dependency errors.

Netlify support suggests you either use a lower version of node when deploying (Just set node version as environmental veriables e.g The `NODE_VERSION` environment variable, or a `.node-version / .nvmrc` file.) or use `--force` when installing the node modules

The error is a peer dependency conflict relating to versions of react, which provides guidance on how you can attempt to resolve it:

> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency  resolution.

It suggests you can run npm install --force or npm install --legacy-peer-deps.

To do this on Netlify you can use the `NPM_FLAGS` environment variable.

```
NPM_FLAGS: used to indicate the flags to pass to the npm install command.
```

Setting it to either `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` depending on your preference.

To add environmental variables there is a section in your project settings named `Envrionment variables`

Please, have a look at the Netlify forum: https://answers.netlify.com/t/deploy-failed-today-build-was-terminated-build-script-returned-non-zero-exit-code-1/64450